# Removing Duplication from array for autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I have a case in which i have combination of numbers and alphabets in an array .I need to remove duplication from my autocomplete.I used $.unique from j query .It works on chrome but not on IE10. What do i do?

Comment: please post your code approach

Answer (score 0):

You can try it .

```js
  var array = ["A","B","C","D","A","F","G" , 1 , 2 , 1 , 3];
  var unique = array.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
      return index == self.indexOf(elem);
  })

  console.log(unique);
```